# Recursively building nested hash from a simple array

Tags: raku

Got this:

```
my @list = <one two three>;

my %hash;
my $item1 = @list.shift;
%hash{$item1} = {$item1 => 1};

my $item2 = @list.shift;
%hash{$item1} = {$item2 => 1};

my $item3 = @list.shift;
%hash{$item1}{$item2} = {$item3 => 1};

say %hash;
```

Outputs this desired data structure:

```
{one => {two => {three => 1}}}
```

Obviously, this would be better if it were recursive, so I wrote this:

```
sub get-hash(%parent-hash, $last-item, *@list) {
    my $item = @list.shift;
    %parent-hash{$last-item} = { $item => 1 };
    get-hash(%parent-hash{$last-item}, $item, @list) if @list;

    return %parent-hash<root>;
}

%hash = get-hash({}, 'root', @list2);
```

Output:

```
{one => {two => {three => 1}}}
```

Though it works, it  feels inelegant, especially having to pass in a `root` argument to the sub and then removing it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Interesting how every `key` nests down to a `value` of 1. @StevieD, have you just written Raku's `singularity` operator?  ;-)

Answer (score 9):

In the upcoming Raku version, there's a neat way to do this:

```
use v6.e.PREVIEW;
my @list = <one two three>;
my %hash;
%hash{||@list} = 1;
say %hash;
```

The `||` indicates that you want to use the list as *multi-dimensional* hash keys.

If you want to stick to things in the current released language versions, you can still call the operator directly, since it's only the syntax sugar that is missing:

```
my @list = <one two three>;
my %hash;
postcircumfix:<{; }>(%hash, @list) = 1;
say %hash
```

The output in either case is as you wish:

```
{one => {two => {three => 1}}}
```

Comment: Nice. I figured there was probably a more raku-ish way of pulling this off. I'll have to check out that operator.

Comment: How do I find documentation for this magic? Couldn't find anything.

Comment: The docs on multi-dimensional indexing are at https://docs.raku.org/language/subscripts#Multiple_dimensions but seem to not mention that one can use them on hashes also.

Comment: OK, I was guessing the semi was doing some kind of multidimensional thing. But I tried moving it around in the braces and got an error so wasn't sure. But what about the postcircumfix: thingy? So that's a method call?

Comment: It's a subroutine call. Nearly all operators in Raku compile into function calls (the exceptions being control-flow affecting ones like `||` and primitives like `=`), so `$a + $b` compiles into `infix:<+>($a, $b)`. Similarly, `@a[$i]` compiles into `postcircumfix:<{ }>(@a, $i)`, and a multi-dimensional index `@a[$i;$j]` compiles into `postcircumfix:<{; }>(@a, ($i, $j))`. You can't move the semicolon around in there since it's just a literal part of the name.

Comment: I suspect @JonathanWorthington means ```%a{$i} compiles into postcircumfix:<{ }>(%a, $i)``` and ```%a{$i;$j} compiles into postcircumfix:<{; }>(%a, ($i, $j))```

Comment: This also, yes. :-)

Comment: Hi jnthn Gonna be 31℃ in Somerset today -- hope wherever you are (Prague?) is cooler. "Nearly all operators in Raku compile into function calls (the exceptions being control-flow affecting ones like `||` and primitives like `=`)" Does the `||` you wrote there just mean the short-circuiting (and hence control-flow affecting) boolean "or" **infix** `||` or does it also mean the sweet **prefix** `||` multi dimensional slipper you introduced in this SO?

Comment: @raiph I was on holiday in the Alps, and high enough up to enjoy weather in the mostly low 20s in the last weeks! :-) I was thinking of `infix:<||>` (short-circuit "or"), although it's the case that in the context of an argument list the `|` is a special form, and the prefix '||` is too in so far as its role is to impact argument passing to the indexing operator.

Answer (score 2):

OK, playing around with the order of the arguments helped simplify things a bit:

```
sub get-hash(@list, %parent-hash = {}, $last-item = 'root') {
    my $item = @list.shift;
    %parent-hash{$last-item} = { $item => 1 };
    get-hash(@list, %parent-hash{$last-item}, $item) if @list;

    return %parent-hash<root>;
}

my @list2 = <one two three>;
%hash = get-hash(@list2);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want ’key-value’ structure `Pair`

```raku
my @list = <one two three>;
say [=>] |@list, 1
```

If you really need `Hash`

```raku
<one two three>
andthen |$_, 1
andthen .reduce: sub ($x,$y) is assoc<right> { %( $x => $y ) }\
andthen .say
```

or

```raku
<one two three>
andthen 1, |.reverse
andthen .reduce:  { %( $^y => $^x ) }\
andthen .say
```